# LWC Deployment Errror

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I'm trying to create a basic LWC for a Community which would be a button where Community admins could set the button text and the page value it should link to.  I don't have any Problems, but when I try to deploy it fails with the following error:

> No base file for markup://c:lwcCommunityButton

Trying to use the `force:source:deploy`  command to deploy to a Dev Ed. Sandbox:

Thanks for any input.

### lwcCommunityButton.html

```
    <template>
    <div class="slds-p-around_none slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_medium slds-m-horizontal_none">
        <lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto">
                <div class="custom-box slds-text-align_center">
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label={ButtonLabel} title={ButtonLabel} onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
                </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </div>
    <c-view-source source="lwc/lwcCommunityButton" slot="footer">
        Navigate to a standard page as defined in the component configuration.
    </c-view-source>
</template>
```

### lwcCommunityButton.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class LwcCommunityButton extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api ButtonLabel;
    @api ButtonPageName;

    handleClick() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__namedPage",
            attributes: {
                pageName: LwcCommunityButton.ButtonPageName
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### lwcCommunityButton.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="lwcCommunityButton">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Page, lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="ButtonLabel" type="String" />
            <property name="ButtonPageName" type="String" placeholder="Enter a Page Name here..."/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: What is c-view-source ?

Comment: Its component from LWC recipe book which redirects to github repo: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/viewSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you cannot define a property for `lightningCommunity__Page`.

If you define any property you get that error. Remove that from component metadata and it will allow you to deploy .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="lwcCommunityButton">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="ButtonLabel" type="String" />
            <property name="ButtonPageName" type="String" placeholder="Enter a Page Name here..."/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: This worked.  I had to keep the lightningCommunity__Page as a <target>, but removed it from the targets parameter in the <targetConfig> tag.  Thanks @pranay-jaiswal !